# contact details at the bottom of a cover letter

Tags: cover-letter

I've read online (on about.com to be precise) that certain types of cover letters that can be closed with the contact details at the bottom, They called this type of cover letters "email cover letters". I would like to know what really qualifies as an email cover letter , would this be a cover letter typed in the email textbox and sent via email or could this mean an attached doc or pdf file provided its sent via email. Why i am interested in knowing this is because in my cover letter i would like to type in my contact details at the bottom of the letter before sending via email. I want to know if its really important where i put my contact details (at the top of the page or at the bottom)

Comment: If you are emailing it, your contact information is embedded into the email header. They don't need to see it written again in your text, they just have to look at the *from* field. Other than that a link to your LinkedIn profile anywhere should do the trick.

Answer (score 1):

It probably doesn't matter whether it's at the top or bottom, as long as the address block is typical for correspondence.